# Придётся ли платить за Java 11?

Tags: java, openjdk, java-11

Читал какие-то английские статьи про обновление java 11, поддержку старых версий и т.д., и общую направленность Oracle сделать java платной по $25 за процессор в месяц. Не знаю как к этому отнестись(мне интересна разработка). Как это повлияет на java в будущем? Не станут ли топ компании переходить с java на что нибудь другое.?

Comment: [Не станут ли топ компании переходить с java на что нибудь другое.?] Думаю, что станут переходить на что-нибудь другое. Или сами напишут новую Яву, или перейдут на какой-нибудь Питон. Да вобщем-то уже есть другие Явы, это всякие Котлины и прочие Голанги.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 полный бред! Топ компании и сейчас платят за поддержку Java, для тех кто не желает платить в будущем всегда есть альтернатива в виде OpenJDK, А всякие там котлины, скалы и прочая шняга как по вашему работать будут без Java? Алексей Алексеич, не беспокойтесь на счёт скорой кончины Java - в обозримом будущем ничего такого не предвидится.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 11):

1. Платной будет LTS версия.
2. Платной она станет через 6 месяцев после выхода. До этого момента можно качать бесплатно. Да и после 6 месяцев можно будет скачать бесплатно архивные версии. А вот обновления не получите, да.
3. Всегда остаётся бесплатный OpenJDK с [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/index.html) (:

Comment: чем LTS версия отличается от обычной?

Comment: @Tsyklop возможностью в случае обнаружения проблем обратиться в техподдержку Oracle.

Answer (score -2):

Популярность питон в последний год выросла выше  джава, наверно не случайно. Писать на 8-9 джаве можно будет смело еще пару-тройку лет смело. А там видно будет, как программисты перестанут учиться на джаве, если она будет платная, настанет закат империи, но думаю вряд ли так сделают. Введут 11 java платную, ее будут юзать 1% и на след год будет опять бесплатная. )))

А так, этот вопрос вызовет бесконечные прения и дискуссии, пока не выйдет 11 java, вот. ))) Закрываем обсуждение. ))

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что популярность питона выросла выше чем явы?

Comment: На хабре вроде был график популярности и статья большая, если найду скину. Но что-то не найти сейчас так сразу.

Comment: На Python хомячки-новички набросились массово, раньше такого языка-выпячки не было, а сейчас куда не загугли, везде сначала бидон, потом начинают варианты своетовать